# How to filter object from model User into list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a list from users I filter, which is here:

`User.objects.filter(groups__name='Staff')`

output which I want it something like

`list_of_usernames = [adam, joe, natalie]`

In list has to be username of the user. Can some please help me to write that query? I tried something to_list but it did not work out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.values_list(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) here:

```
list_of_usernames = list(
    User.objects.filter(groups__name='Staff').values_list('username', flat=True)
)
```

But actually it is usually better to fetch model objects, and fetch the attribute, such that the logic in the model is not "bypassed":

```
from operator import attrgetter

list_of_usernames = list(map(
    attrgetter('username'),
    User.objects.filter(groups__name='Staff')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't need any other attribute from the user for later use, just do:

```
list_of_usernames = [u.username for u in User.objects.filter(groups__name='Staff')]
```